# How to compare two 2D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison, 2d

I have two 2D arrays of different lengths both of type double. I am trying to compare the contents of the first array with the contents of the second one. However, the score is increasing when one of the values in the first element is equal to one in the second not when both the values of i and j are equal to both the value of x and y. Can somebody help me please? The code i'm using can be found below:

```
    if (result1.Length <= result2.Length)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < result1.Length / 2; j++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = 0; y < result2.Length / 2; y++)
                            {
                                if (result1.GetValue(i, j).Equals(result2.GetValue(x, y)))
                                {
                                    score++;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on your comments, below, I think that you need to check first-column-equality and second-column-equality at the same time, and only increment score if both match.

```
if (result1.Length <= result2.Length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < result1.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < result2.Length; j++)
        {
            if (result1[i,0] == result2[j,0] && result1[i,1] == result2[j,1])
            {
                score++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is search every element in result2 for each element in result1. The results are obtained from a text file which has two columns, thus the need to use a 2d array to store the results. the score will be used to compare how similar the arrays are. i will also have to choose the start and end positions of the arrays where they are similar however i'll deal with that once the elements are being compared properly.

Comment: Does result1 represent the first column of the text file, and result2 represent the second column?

Can you give some sample input and output?

Comment: result1 is one text file and result2 is another text file.

Comment: Result1 

-5 1
2 1
-4 2.66667
2 0.6
5 0.625
-5 1
2 1
-4 2.66667
2 0.6
2 1
0 1.66667
-2 0.6
0 1.66667
2 0.6
0 1.66667
-4 2
0 1
2 0.3
2 1.42857

Comment: Result2

3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-3 0.0921053
3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-8 0.0777778
1 3
-1 0.333333
0 3
5 0.394737
3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-3 0.0921053
3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-8 0.0777778
1 0.6
4 1.97368
3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-3 0.0921053
3 5.42857
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-8 0.0777778
1 3
-1 0.333333
0 3
0 0.608696
0 3.28571
-8 0.0777778
1 3
-1 1
0 1
0 1
0 1

Comment: those are the input. If for example 0 1 (the 17th element from result1) is chosen, the answer should be 3 as there are 3 elements with values 0 1 stored in result2

Answer (score 0):

try it instead:

```
if(result1[i,j] == result2[i,j])
score++;
```

Comment: it still does not work. the problem is that it is comparing just the i values not the i and j values